# Should I request a title change and another increase after initial increase?

Tags: salary, title

### Background Info

I am a application supervisor (we're known as working supervisors which basically means we are team leads, we know the technology and the framework based on our experience) for a company I've been with for quite some time.

I have been with the company for 16 years and report directly to our VP.  This was the first year I reported to the VP as last year the company restructured and the VP took ownership of the development team (as strange as that sounds).

### Work

In any event this year has been a very very good year in terms of what we accomplished.  I lead a whole slew of initiatives and the application we built has vastly helped our HR folks, our Engineering folks, as well as a few other teams.  Not to sound a trumpet but I basically worked very hard and ensured we went above and beyond in terms of how to move our company in the right direction in terms of software.

### Review Time

During this time of year we are having our reviews and I thought for the effort I had put forth this year I was sure to get at least 6-7% increase of my salary.

During our review we go through some metrics that our generated from a system called echospan.  Its basically a point system where you rank your self and then your manager ranks you.  You end up with [some sort of radar chart or spider graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radar_chart) that gives you an easy to see view of whether you and your manager are aligned.  Your manager does not see your self review until he/she reviews you as well.

After my manager (the vp) did my review the spider graph was almost exact - that is me and my boss are very inline and in sync on how we work together and what he expects of me.  He praised me for my contributions and how I lead by example.  He mentioned he really loves my work ethic and how my position is very challenging yet I was able to succeed from every aspect of it.  He also said he was impressed with the way I handled myself when I had to deal with many different departments in the company.  He stated

> "..some people tried to give you grief in terms of the application you
>   guys are workign on, but you took it as feedback and improved the
>   applications.  I even got emails from people in the company stating
>   how great the system is".

All in all the review was very good and I scored a 3.8 out of a max of 4.0 in this review system.

He handed me a piece of paper and said you have been given a 4% increase (which to me isn't too bad although as I mentioned I was really thinking I would have a 6-7% increase).  I didn't really fight for more as he made a comment about

> "if I gave you 5% or more I would have to make the case to the board
>   members about a change of title."

### VP now wants to add responsibilities

Not letting the 4% bother me I was ready to call it a day and leave when the VP mentioned hold on I have one thing to say.  He then proceeded to tell me how becuase of my work ethic and the way I currently lead my team he would like me to keep my current role but take over our documentation team (6 other people).  He stated that he liked my organization skills, my people skills, and my determination to simply "work smart and get things done".  He told me this would be effective this January 2017.  He then closed with lets talk next week about this and tell me if you want to proceed.

Now I'm thinking of what he said earlier, where he mentioned if he would of gave me 5% or more he would have to request a title change.  Well hello, here was your opportunity.  Now I'm in a dilemma, should I take on this new position with my normal 4% increase and no title change or should I request a title change and ask for more money.  It's odd I just got an increase but then I'm asking for more...I know it sounds greedy but I wasn't under the impression that I would be taking on this new role.

**At the end of the day I need to put a roof over my head and feed my kids**.  No I don't only work for money but I work because I like it but I'd like to be compensated correctly.  What do you guys think is it worth asking for a new title and an additional increase in my salary or just take the new position?

I am in the USA if that helps and have been with the same company for 16 years.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere - But does asking hurt me ?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere - I wasn't going to be disappointed or harsh in any way.  What do you think if I phrased it in a way like so..."Thank you for considering me and showing the confidence and trust you have in me - I appreciate that.  I feel as though the additional responsibility is worth a change in title / pay.  During the review process you had mentioned that anything more than what you had given me requires board level approval.  I believe this in fact should be presented to the board as a change in title.  We've accomplished a lot together and I think my work ethic shows it - don't you agree".

Comment: It is really hard to get the second sentence out...as I cannot find the right words to use...

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Does that second sentence sound okay to you?  I cannot seem to fit it into the thanks without going off topic or at least sounding like I totally shifted gears.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank your boss for trusting you with the new responsibility and gladly accept. Then tell him to please go to the board as “this should now be an easy case to make.”

**If board comes back with a No**, ask your boss : ”What do I need to do to get this promotion?”. Start doing those things. Then begin to quietly look for another job – Do not accept a lateral move, get the raise and promotion you deserve – either internally or externally.

**If your boss refuses to go to the board**, ask him why – then respectfully express your disappointment in him and ask him where he sees your future with the company. Then begin to quietly look for another job – Do not accept a lateral move, get the raise and promotion you deserve – either internally or externally.

Comment: So accept the position before he even has a chance to go to bat for me?

Comment: Yes. It shows good faith. You are working on the company best interests & you expect the same from them. I don't think threatening to not do work assigned can help you in any way. Even if it did, you would have to leave anyhow as your relationship is no longer based  trust. Worst case, you are only doing the extra work for a few month till you find a new Job. Also refusing to do the work will broadcast just how unhappy you are & they will KNOW you are looking for a new job. You want to take your time & find the right job  (Promotion&raise). So you need to keep playing the "good employee" game.

Comment: I have to find the right words to state this.  I like the way you mentioned gladly accept then tell him to please go to the board as "this should be an easy case to make" but I need to phrase it in some better wording.  Can you edit this a bit to touch on that part ?

Comment: If I gladly accept and my boss hits point or case 2 "If your boss refuses to go to the board" but I had already "gladly accepted" so basically I am stuck doing the work with no further increase and no title change - is that correct?  Wouldn't he tell me right away whether he goes to the board or not?  That should indicate to him whether I accept this new role or not.

Comment: to answer your second comment : How about: “This year has been a very good year in terms of what we accomplished. I lead a whole slew of initiatives and the application we built has vastly helped our HR folks, our Engineering folks, as well as a few other teams. I worked very hard and ensured we went above and beyond in terms of how to move our company in the right direction. Now you are also giving me the documentation team -  I think the board will agree that this warrants a Title change. Do you think they wont? ”

Comment: To answer the 3rd : I think that even hinting at a change of behavior from what you have been doing all along is bad idea, and it won't help your case. While accepting the additional work unconditionally will. (Its not really unconditional as you will quit.. just not now). See my reasoning baive

Comment: I gotta say this is a darn good answer - thank you for the feedback.

Comment: Disclaimer : I'm in a very similar situation this year (but hadn't had my review yet- but am expecting to be low balled).. this is may plan. I'm selfishly seeing you as a Ginny-pig - so let me know how it goes!!

Comment: That is funny...well I will update this or at least comment next week as that is my next meeting with him.  The only issue is although the VP is nice he's one of those quick to the gun kind of guys and he might fire back with something like "...well I think you should take what we've given you and prove that you are mgmt material, as that is my goal to bring you into mgmt".  You know what I mean, these guys could sell you a run down broken car and you'd fall for it...

Comment: I seemed to have succeeded partly.  And I promised I'd write back.  I took it upon myself to schedule a meeting with the VP yesterday.  As he had asked for a discussion about my thoughts on this change and to circle back to him.  The conversation started pretty good with just some normal how's it going sort of stuff.  Then he discussed whether or not I had thought about it.  I immediately thanked him and expressed interested but mentioned that my role is more of a managerial role than that of a supervisor (they are much different roles).  I gave him solid points why I should have...

Comment: ...A title change and he agreed but really wanted to see how I progress with this additional set of responsibilities.  However, he said with that title change comes a wage increase...yes another wage increase.  So I did get a change of title and a wage increase as well.

Answer (score 1):

The way business generally works is that a promotion is an opportunity to prove you are worth more. Do so, *then* make the case for a raise. Yes, that requires good faith on both sides, but if you can't count on that you are in trouble anyway. It also requires patience on your part, but  again that is something you need to have to survive.

The only reliable way to get both at once is to change employers.